# Building javascript array but has null values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Json String: (response)

```
{"19":{"id":"19","name":"Product","sku":123,"price":"59.50","cost":"25.00"},"20":{"id":"20","name":"Test","sku":456,"price":"50.00","cost":"40.00"}}
```

JavaScript Code:

```
  var json = $.parseJSON(response);
  var items = new Array();

  $.each(json, function(index, value){
    items[index] = value.id;
  });

  console.log(items);
  // returns  [ , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 19, 20 ]
```

I have a JSON object that's originally built from a php array and converted using json_encode.  When I loop through the object - to build a new array based off some of the values, it has null as all the first items, then the last two has the the actual id.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are building an object with properties named `19` and `20`.  Use `[` and `]` to create an array.

Comment: You say the JSON is converted from a PHP array, but that JSON is an object not an array. If your expecting an array you need to fix the PHP. if you want an array of ID's in the javascript from that object use items.push( value.id) in the $.each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using an array for `items`.  When you set `items[19]`, it needs to set values 0-18 first (these are the "null" values).  This is because JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays, only numeric.

Try using an object for `items` instead.

```
var items = {};

$.each(json, function(index, value){
  items[index] = value.id;
});

console.log(items); // {19: 19, 20: 20}
```

P.S. The "null" items in the array are actually `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using the index from the object, you are creating a sparse array. The object has properties named "19" and "20", and as you use those as the index in the array, that's where you will get the values from the properties.

If you want to pack the items from the beginning of the array, just `push` them:

```
$.each(json, function(index, value){
  items.push(value.id);
});
```

Result in `items`:

```
[ "19", "20" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also change the JSON response to an array, if possible:

```
[
  {"id":"19","name":"Product","sku":123,"price":"59.50","cost":"25.00"},
  {"id":"20","name":"Test","sku":456,"price":"50.00","cost":"40.00"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

> When setting a property on a JavaScript array when the property is a valid array index and that index is outside the current bounds of the array, the array will grow to a size large enough to accommodate an element at that index, and the engine will update the array's length property accordingly:

You are setting array[19] to a value, so array[0-18] become undefined.

To fix this problem, declare items as an object instead, which can have numerical properties assigned without automatically populating the lower ranges.